# Mouse double click windowsformhost on a usercontrol with a spreadsheet

Tags: wpf, vb.net, user-controls

I have a usercontrol that contains a spread and I have this methods

```
Public Event DOBLECLICK()
Public Sub sp1_CellDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As FarPoint.Win.Spread.CellClickEventArgs)
        RaiseEvent DOBLECLICK()
End Sub
```

and in the `mainwindow.xaml` in the function  `MainWindow_Loaded` I have:

```
AddHandler host.sp1.CellDoubleClick, AddressOf host.sp1_CellDoubleClick
```

my question is, how can i use the event of double click and when clicked i hide the windowsformhost i know that i can hide it whit 
`WinFormsHost.Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Hidden` but how to when clicked the doubleclick on the spread.

Comment: Maybe put `WinFormsHost.Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Hidden` in `sp1_CellDoubleClick`? It is quite unclear of what your question is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i got it,

in the user control put this:

```
Public Event Dobleclick()

Private Sub sp1_CellDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As FarPoint.Win.Spread.CellClickEventArgs) Handles spEmpresas.CellDoubleClick
        RaiseEvent Dobleclick()
End Sub
```

and in the MainWindow.xaml:

```
Imports nameofyourprogram.Control
Public Class MainWindow
Dim host As New nameofyourprogram.Control

Public Sub MainWindow_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded


AddHandler host.Dobleclick, AddressOf doubleclick

end sub

Sub doubleclick()
 msgbox("now you can work whit and event in your mainwindow ")
 'after this message i want to hide my windownforhost
 WinFormsHost.Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Hidden
end sub

End Class
```